# Virtual host showing apache test page and everything else in doc root is forbidden

Tags: apache, centos, config

I am using a new CentOS 6.3 minimal install with fresh httpd installed

When I go to my virtual host it is showing me the apache test page, and then if I go to mydomain.co.uk/index.html (That I have just set up to test with) it says forbidden. All the usual answers to this don't seem to be working and I have honestly looked through tons of forums and other people questions/answers and nothing seems to be working for me.

I have created a group called 'www' that I have added the user 'apache' to.. This is my root directory in httpd.conf file, I have left it pretty open just for testing:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

This is my vhosts file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.co.uk
  ServerAlias www.domain.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html
  <Directory "/home/domain/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From /home/ onwards I have set the group to www

When ls -lA on home folder I get

```
drwxrwsr-x.   5 root www   4096 Feb  5 20:57 home
```

The error I am getting in my logs file is a permission one:

```
[Wed Feb 06 10:24:42 2013] [error] [client 62.254.7.226] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path '/home/domain/public_html/index.html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

As is everything else in that folder. I really don't know what to try next. I have come to the point of needing to ask for my specific setup as following other tutorials or answers has not worked for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selinux is not expecting the http server to access files under /home/domain since it is not a standard path.

You can change it with following command:

```
chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /home/domain/public_html/
```

Answer (score 2):

Error 13 means that the user/group specified in your apache configuration (httpd.conf) didn't have permission to access the files.  The files, and all the directories above them, need to have permission that allow for that user and group.

One of the trickier bits can be extended permissions.  If you are running selinux, the server user could be denied because of the extended permissions on the file.  To check for this, run (from the command line):

```
setenforce 0
```

If the problem goes away (i.e. the page is visible) then your extended permissions are blocking access.

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied for details.